# Is there a word for the next upcoming event chronologically?

Tags: single-word-requests, time, future

If we have a bunch of events coming up in the future, and I want to refer to the next one coming up (chronologically) - is there a word I can use ?

Comment: Some example, please?

Comment: Um, the *next* one?

Comment: As @YosefBaskin states, provide an example sentence of how such a word would be used. Since you use the [tag:future-tense] tag, does this mean you want a verb?

Comment: The first of the upcoming events....

Comment: "I'm going to check the diary and get back to you with [the next event in chronological order]"

Actually, I'm developing a piece of software and I needed to create a module that returns [the next event in chronological order]  but I need a concise way of saying it,

Comment: On deck, if you like baseball metaphors.

Answer (score 0):

Next, followed by...ect these are a few but there are more bellow.

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/upcoming

Answer (score 0):

What immediately comes to my mind is "subesquent".

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/subsequent

Comment: I had thought of subsequent, but this could refer to any number, or model of car or anything - I specifically wanted to refer to an event or occurence